# Ruby wrapper for stackoverflow api - Serel, Pilha

Tags: support, ruby

Serel and pilha are good Ruby wrappers for the StackExchange API, but I am not able to access the body method for question and answers. The body method returns nil.

I want the content of questions and answers. How can I get them?

Also I have used Nokogiri to extract content, but sometimes I get an "internal error 500". Why is this so? Do they block the scraper #Nokogiri after some attempts?

Comment: For the record, Nokogiri isn't a scraper, it's an XML/HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't use Ruby (and consequently have not used the two libraries you've mentioned), I'm going to guess that the problem is that you aren't specifying [a filter](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) that includes `body`.

By default, post body is not included in the JSON returned by API methods and must explicitly be requested by creating a filter that includes it. The `withbody` filter, for example, would include `body` in the response.

You will likely want to consult the documentation for each library for instructions on setting a filter.